# Unity3d declare different script as 'using ___'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a project that requires underwater physics, and from my `WaterController.cs` script I need to get variables from the `FirstPersonController.cs` script. I was wondering if I could put it at the top with "using" like `using FirstPersonController.cs` or something along those lines. Could someone tell me if I could do this and in what way, or if there is another way of getting variables from that script?

Comment: Are you trying to access static variables or member variables of a FirstPersonController instance?

Comment: Check this: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10857/how-can-i-access-other-scripts-and-their-functions.html. You never put a class in `using` you add `namespace` there and then access class in your code. If you still couldn't understand what I am talking about. Put some of your code you want to access.

Comment: @GuntherFox I am pretty new to C#, so that only made a little bit of sense, but all I can tell you is that the variables in the FirstPersonController script are not static.

Comment: @JoeP. Oh!  Is this Unity's Standard Asset `FirstPersonController.cs`?

Comment: @GuntherFox Yes, attached to the FPSController prefab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FirstPersonController.cs` that comes with Unity3d's standard assets belongs to the `UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson` namespace so you need

`using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;`

at the top of any script that needs to use that class. Since you're trying to access one of its public member variables, you also need a reference to the instance of the `FirstPersonController` that you're working with.

In `WaterController.cs`, you'll need a reference to the `GameObject` that the `FirstPersonController` is attached to (lets call it `FPobj`) and then you can get that component like this:

```
FPobj.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>(); // Returns null or the reference
```

If you're having trouble "getting a reference" to the `GameObject` that the `FirstPersonController` is attached to, try this:

Give `WaterController` a public variable to hold it:

```
public class WaterController : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject FPobj;
    private FirstPersonController FPC;

    void Start() {
        FPC = FPobj.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>();
    }
}
```

Now, when you click on the `GameObject` that has the `WaterController` attached, you will see a slot in Unity's *Inspector* for FPobj (becuase it's `public`).  You can drag your `GameObject` that has `FirstPersonController` attached from the *Hierarchy* into this slot and you should be good to go.  Now, anywhere in your `WaterController`'s functionality, you can use `FPC` to get the variables you need.  Since they're all `private`, you'll need to modify `FirstPersonController.cs` if you'd like to access them:

```
float GetYRotation() { return m_YRotation(); } // or whatever variable you want.
```

There are also other options for getting the reference without dragging into the *Hierarchy*.  You can, for example, make use of `GameObject.Find()` or `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag()`.  If you go this route, make sure you still do it in `Start()` only once and save the reference instead of calling it every time you need it... those two functions are pretty slow.

Comment: It seems like it should work. I've seen some answers that look similar to this, but none of them use a `GameObject` to get the component from.

Comment: @JoeP. It might be possible to make FPC public, drag the object into that slot, and skip the `GameObject` step but I'm not positive.

Comment: Unity isn't making the GameObject slot in the editor. Any reason why this might be?

Comment: @JoeP. Make sure it's `public`, it's not `static`, and there are no compiler errors.  It wont show up until there are no compiler errors.

Comment: `Assets/Scripts/Entire Game/WaterController.cs(10,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FirstPersonController' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

Comment: @JoeP. Ah! My apologies... it looks like it does exist in a namespace.  You'll need `using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;` at the top of your file.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I noticed that it says I can drag a FPSController into the FirsPersonController slot. Does this mean I don't need the FPobj?

Comment: @JoeP. Yes, possibly.  If you make it public and it makes a slot and that works, then go about that route.

Comment: Ok, just one last question. When I get the component `FirstPersonController` from FPC, it still doesn't give me options for variables. When I type in the variable name, such as `m_WalkSpeed`, it shows red and gives me the error: `UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.FirstPersonController does not contain a definition for m_WalkSpeed`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99337/discussion-between-joe-p-and-gunther-fox).